# JQuery AJAX on a Form Submission not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I can't for the life of me figure out why this won't work.

I can invoke `alert("Error: City not found. Please try again.");` and `alert("Error: City too ambiguous, please try again.");`

But this does not submit the form! Why is that?

```
//why won't this submit the form???
if (codes.length == 1) {
  $('#city_number').val(codes); 
  return true;
} 

$('#real-estate-search').submit(function() {
  //users won't always click the drop down, so we need to have a best 
  //guess script which guesses which city the customer wants. 
    
  //get the radio status 
  radio_selection = $('input[name=search_type]:checked', '#real-estate-search').val();
  if(radio_selection == 'city' && !$('#city_number').val() 
     && $('#search_query').val()) {
    alert("if fired!");
    $.ajax({  
      type: "GET",  
      url: "includes/autocomplete.php",  
      data: "query="+ $('#search_query').val(),  
      success: function(data){  
        alert("ajax success!");
        return_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        codes = return_data.data;
        error = null;
        if (codes.length == 0) {
          alert("Error: City not found. Please try again.");
          return false;
        }
        if (codes.length > 1) {
          alert("Error: City too ambiguous, please try again.");
          return false;
        }
        if (codes.length == 1) {
          $('#city_number').val(codes);
          return true;
        }                          
      }
    }); //end of ajax function
  } else return true;
  
  return false;           
});
```

Comment: what is the type of `$('#real-estate-search')` `form` or `input`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the AJAX request takes place asynchronously, the submit method will have already returned false while the call was taking place, meaning the return true will do nothing, since it's no longer in the `submit()` scope.

What you need to do is get the callback to initiate the form submit again instead of returning true.

```
if (codes.length == 1) {
   $('#city_number').val(codes);   
   $('#real-estate-search').submit();
}
```

And add a statement that means it wont need to get verified the second time.

Answer (score 0):

```
var canSend = false;
$('#real-estate-search').submit(function() {
  if ( !canSend ) {
  //users won't always click the drop down, so we need to have a best 
  //guess script which guesses which city the customer wants. 

  //get the radio status 
  radio_selection = $('input[name=search_type]:checked', '#real-estate-search').val();
  if(radio_selection == 'city' && !$('#city_number').val() 
     && $('#search_query').val()) {
    alert("if fired!");
    $.ajax({  
      type: "GET",  
      url: "includes/autocomplete.php",  
      data: "query="+ $('#search_query').val(),  
      success: function(data){  
        alert("ajax success!");
        return_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        codes = return_data.data;
        error = null;
        if (codes.length == 0) {
          alert("Error: City not found. Please try again.");
          return false;
        }
        if (codes.length > 1) {
          alert("Error: City too ambiguous, please try again.");
          return false;
        }
        if (codes.length == 1) {
          $('#city_number').val(codes);
          canSend = true;
          $('#real-estate-search');
        }                          
      }
    }); //end of ajax function
  } else return true;
  return false;//return false if the form is not valid

  } else {
    return true;//return true if codes.length == 1
  }
});
```